# How come the exact same version of Google Chrome shows different layout?

Tags: php, html, css, browser, layout

I have google chrome on two computers here. Both run XP.

I get some DIVS dispositioned in one of them, and perfect in the other.

They are the exact same version when I check "about chrome"...

I have cleared cache and all.

Very strange to me....

Any ideas?

Also, I have the same issue with IE8, but I don't know if it is the EXACT same version, because I forgot to check the last nr in the version on the other computer.

Anyways, how can this happen?

If you need the css etc just let me know, but it shouldn't be the problem. Or?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm. Maybe something to do with fonts installed on the two computers and/or versions of said fonts.

That's the only thing I can think of that might change the positioning in two identical browsers.

Comment: On a related note, perhaps the zoom level of the webpage is an issue? Something which might be worth checking.

Comment: Shynthriir - That seemed to be it... The zoom in and out... This affects the DIVS positions, as they are positioned relative... How should I position them now, hmmmm?

Comment: I fixed it. I had forgotten a closing tag, so this caused the DIVS to move WITH the ZOOM for some reason, When I closed the tag of a table, then the DIVS stayed put even when zooming... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Some possible problems that I can think :

- Resolution of the computers. Especially if you're using any % based positioning/scaling in your CSS.
- Default font face if you're not specifying
- Google Chrome has a bug with the body sometimes not filling the viewport, if content doesn't. This can normally be fixed by toggling full screen on/off, but I doubt this has to do with your problem.

The first thing I'd check is the resolution, and your positioning. CSS of the `div` in question would help.